# To check the multiple condition of different columns and if one of them not satisfied then status should be No

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Source DataFrame:

```
cell|hr|erb|hrab|status| KPI  
10  |8 |8  |2   |yes   |
9   |7 |8  |2   |yes   |
9   |8 |6  |1   |no    |erab
10  |5 |8  |3   |no    |hr,Hrab
10  |8 |4  |2   |no    |erb
10  |8 |8  |2   |yes   |
```

Condition:

```
cell>=5,hr>=7,erb>=7,hrab<=2
```

The task is to find *status*.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and **ask a question**. It is not enough to describe a task, as this is not a code-writing service.

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to the title of your post, you want to create not only *status*
column, but also *KPI* - a list of column names which don't meet your
requirements.

This is why I had to completely rework my initial solution.

Start with defining a function to generate the list of "source columns",
which don't meet your requirements for the current row:

```
def errSrc(row):
    causes = pd.Series([
        None if row.cell >= 5 else 'cell',
        None if row.hr   >= 7 else 'hr',
        None if row.erb  >= 7 else 'erb',
        None if row.hrab <= 2 else 'hrab' ])
    return ','.join(causes.dropna())
```

Then compute the source for *KPI* column, so far as a temporary variable:

```
kpi = df.apply(errSrc, axis=1)
```

No new column has been generated yet, since *kpi* will be used in 2 ways:

- to generate *status* column (empty string should generate "yes",
  and non-empty string - "no"),
- to create *KPI* column itself.

And the actual creation of new columns can be performed as:

```
df = df.assign(status=np.where(kpi.str.len(), 'no', 'yes'), KPI=kpi)
```

Note that `kpi.str.len()` in *boolean* context yields *True* for
string length > 0 and *False* for an empty string.
So there is no need for `> 0` in this place.

`df.assign` creates a new DataFrame with some columns added and it is
saved back in *df*, overwriting its previous content.

The result, for your source data, is:

```
   cell  hr  erb  hrab status      KPI
0    10   8    8     2    yes         
1     9   7    8     2    yes         
2     9   8    6     1     no      erb
3    10   5    8     3     no  hr,hrab
4    10   8    4     2     no      erb
5    10   8    8     2    yes
```

And the last remark: It is a bad habbit to start with a relatively simple
question and then stepwise add further requirements.
You should put all requirements in the original post.

Comment: now how to find KPI that  doesn't satisfied condition